# Swagger: how to combine shared information from different APIs

Tags: java, swagger

I am adding swagger 1.5.0 support to an existing java application that implements 20+ different REST APIs and uses Jersey 1.17.1 with package scanning. Does anyone have any best practice recommendations? For example:

- Should swagger definitions be added to each java class or can they be
  added to an independent file(s) to avoid touching each class?
- Each API requires the same set of headers which I have defined in great details for the first class using @ApiImplicitParam. Instead of
  repeating that information for every operation of every class, is
  there a way to apply it to all APIs?

Answer (score 0):

There are a zillion ways to integrate the swagger 1.5.x libraries (note: 1.5.10 is latest) with a JAX-RS application.  I suggest you follow a scheme like in the swagger-petstore and split the files by top-level path segments, which should provide a logical organization.

For repeated headers, you can have each resource class extend a base class which has an annotated class-level variable.  That will apply to each operation in the classes that extend it.

Comment: Thank you. I have browsed through the pet store example. It has been designed and implemented as a swagger application to start with; I would have to make a lot of wholesale changes to my app to mimic what that app has done. If there is a portion of the example that would relate to my app I would appreciate pointing it out. 

The 2nd response is very exciting as all my API classes extend a base class already. I tried a few different things with no avail. Can you elaborate on how to implement that (e.g. which annotations to be used in the base class, in the API classes, …)?

Comment: I got it working by defining common parameters in the base class and specific parameters in the API classes. Thanks.